# Stem and Branch of plants

Tags: botany, homework, terminology, plant-anatomy

What is the difference between the stem of a plant and the branch of a plant. Is the branch part of the stem?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, first, we must define the terms. Major primary plant organs can be characterized as either [roots, stems, or leaves](https://www.jove.com/science-education/11090/basic-plant-anatomy-roots-stems-and-leaves). A [stem](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-biology/chapter/stems/) is a structure that contains nodes and internodes (as a previous answer explains), and axillary buds. These buds mean that stems can give rise to more stems, roots, or leaves.

[Branches](http://www.biologydiscussion.com/plant-morphology/branching-meaning-and-types-botany/48893) can be defined as stems arising from an axillary bud of another stem. In this way, all branches are stems, but not all stems are branches. Beware of confusing the botanical definition of branches (arising from axillary buds) from the colloquial definition of a branch (a tree branch) because... all tree branches arise from axillary buds, but not all botanical branches are found on trees!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The term "Branch" used in school textbooks generally mean stem branch and the stem branches are stem in morphological identity because they have nodes, internodes, leaves, and exogenous development.

Comment: I am trying to reach Fahn and Esau but in lockdown I wont be able to acces library :(